# Ping option to know whether net is not in a proper way

Tags: internet, connection, ping

I need the option of ping which,If the net is disconnected, the pinging need to be stopped.Now if the net connection lost,It will wait and will continue after net came..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `man ping`

-c count

Stop  after  sending  count  ECHO_REQUEST packets. With deadline
option, ping waits for count ECHO_REPLY packets, until the time‐
 out expires.

```
$ ping www.google.nl -c 5
PING www.l.google.com (66.102.13.104) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ez-in-f104.1e100.net (66.102.13.104): icmp_req=1 ttl=53 time=18.4 ms
64 bytes from ez-in-f104.1e100.net (66.102.13.104): icmp_req=2 ttl=53 time=18.8 ms
64 bytes from ez-in-f104.1e100.net (66.102.13.104): icmp_req=3 ttl=53 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from ez-in-f104.1e100.net (66.102.13.104): icmp_req=4 ttl=54 time=16.8 ms
64 bytes from ez-in-f104.1e100.net (66.102.13.104): icmp_req=5 ttl=54 time=19.6 ms

--- www.l.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.133/17.781/19.660/1.615 ms
```